# Difference between declaring variable

Tags: javascript

what is the difference between the way a variable can be declared?

```
a = 5;
```

and

```
var a = 5;
```

Is there any relation with scoping also?

Comment: a = 5; a is global;
var a = 5; a is local;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a = 5 will declare a global variable from any scope. var a = 5 will declare a variable within the declared scope.

```
 a = 5;    //global variable
 var b = 6; // global variable
 function foo(){
  var c = 7; //local variable
  d = 9; //global variable
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`var a` will create local variable. The other will create and/or set a global variable.

Most of the time, you are better off creating local variables, unless you absolutely need to create a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

One declares a variable, the other one doesn't.

The `var` keyword is for declaring variables, and the variable is created in the current scope.

If you assign a value to a variable that doesn't exist yet, the variable is implicitly created in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 5;
```

This will set a variable, if the variable has not already been declared then it will be created in the global scope (which you probably don't want).

```
var a = 5;
```

This will create and set a variable.  The variable will be created as a local variable in the function scope if inside a function, otherwise will create it globally.

Also worth noting that the statement var a = 5 will be hoisted to the top of your function.  I.e.

```
function() {
    doSomestuff();
    a = 4;
    var a = 5;
    doOtherStuff();
}
```

actually becomes

```
function() {
    var a = 5;
    doSomestuff();
    a = 4;
    doOtherStuff();
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var for more info.

Also worth noting that if you use strict mode you cannot declare a variable with just a = 5.  You must use the var keyword.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

This is worth doing because turns your undetectable mistakes into obvious errors.